# Probability of an sequence of independent random 2-dimensional vectors

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(X_n\mid n=1,2,\ldots)$ be a sequence independent of random $2$-dimensional vectors, where, for each $n$, $X_n$ is uniformly distributed on the square with vertices $(\pm n,\pm n)$. Calculate the probability that $\left|X_n\right|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem. I just don't know how to solve it or what kind of definition I should use.

I've trying to use the Borel-Cantanelli lemma but I'm kind of confused because the problem says that we are talking about a 2-dimensional vectors.

That means that we aro going to have $(X_1,X_2)$ a.v's independent or a sequence of different 2-dimensional vector. The Borel-Cantanelli lemma just talks about a sequence not a sequence of sequences. That is where I'm confused.

Comment: Is this a tail event? If so, might Kolmogorov's zero–one law or a Borel–Cantelli lemma help?

Comment: The same answer to your previous question also applies here -- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543383/probability-of-a-independent-sequence-of-random-variables

Comment: Indeed the same approach works. Try $$A_n=[|X_n|<n^\alpha]$$ for some well chosen $\alpha$.